# How to create multiple events using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I want to create multiple events with multiple dates using this plugin.

```
 $("#tempust").tempust({
            date: new Date("2017/12/12"),
            offset: 1,
            events: {
                "2017/12/12": $("<div>jQueryScript Event</div>")
            }
        });
        $("#tempust").on("changeDate", function (event) {
            $("#output")
            .append("Date Changed!")
            .append("<br/>");
        });
```

Plugin demo url: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Dynamic-Event-Calendar-Plugin-tempust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to initialise with multiple events like so:

```
$("#tempust").tempust({
    date: new Date("2017/12/12"),
    offset: 1,
    events: {
        "2017/12/12": $("<div>Event on today!</div>"),
        "2017/12/13": $("<div>Event on today as well!</div>"),
    }
});
And to set multiple events you do this:

$("#tempust").tempust("setEvents", {
    "2017/12/12": $("<div>Event on today!</div>"),
    "2017/12/13": $("<div>Event on today as well!</div>"),
});
```